# Can't bind proxy address to apt

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, apt

I have installed proxy (Network settings). It's working.
Having run `sudo apt update` I "clashed" an error

> E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/sudo apt-get Release'
> does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't
> be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See
> apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
> details.

That's strange as `curl -v https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/` prints normally.
I guess it's because APT does not know of my proxy. Am I mistaken?
How do I correctly set and use proxy for apt?

Answer (score 0):

`apt` keeps a separate proxy configuration. Create a file called `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf` and add the following:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.host:port/"; 
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.host:port/";
```

Then run `apt update` again.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.2/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 127.0.0.1 4711]

Comment: Apparently, APP failed to proxy its traffic.

Comment: The `127.0.0.1 4711` in your output seems to suggest that apt already has a proxy configuration somehow. You'd have to review `/etc/apt` to figure out why.